# [material-ui],[redux-from] Select with dynamic options

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I request data from the backend. The data is the gift data and the person data.

My goal is to realize connect the gift and the person. Each person takes a gift.

I use the `material-ui` and the `redux-form` package.

The person data tree is like:

```
persons: "
        [ {
            name:'person1_name',
            userID:'person1_userID',
            hobbies: persondata -> the same to persons  
           },
           {
            name:'person2_name',
            userID:'person2_userID',
            hobbies: persondata -> the same to persons  
           }, 
           {
            name:'person3_name',
            userID:'person3_userID',
            hobbies: persondata -> the same to persons  
           }
          ]
```

I want to get this result: 
     I click the `select`, 3 (if the backend person data is 3 persons) person `item`(option) is showed.

I use the redux state `state.sendGood.driftMemberArray.formData` to save person data.

My code is below:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Field, FieldArray, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { connect }   from 'react-redux'
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField'
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem'

const renderSelectField = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, children, ...custom }) => (
    <SelectField
        floatingLabelText={label}
        errorText={touched && error}
        {...input}
        onChange={(event, index, value) => input.onChange(value)}
        children={children}
        {...custom}/>
)

const renderMembers = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed } }) => (
    <ul>
      {fields.map((member, index) =>
          <li key={index}>
            <Field name={`${member}.selectMan`} component={renderSelectField} label="select a man">
              {member.hobbies.map( (item,keyIndex) =>
                 <MenuItem  key={keyIndex} value={keyIndex} primaryText='hahah'/>
              )}
            </Field>
          </li>
      )}
    </ul>
)


let NextWeekDriftForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = props;
  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <FieldArray name="members"component={renderMembers}/>
        </div>
      </form>
  )
}

NextWeekDriftForm =  reduxForm({
  form: 'NextWeekDriftForm',     // a unique identifier for this form
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(NextWeekDriftForm)

export default NextWeekDriftForm =  connect(
    state => ({
      initialValues:state.sendGood.driftMemberArray.formData,
    })
) (NextWeekDriftForm)
```

As a result, the error show:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

`{member.hobbies.map( (item,keyIndex) =>
                     <MenuItem  key={keyIndex} value={keyIndex} primaryText='hahah'/>`

My problem is probably in this code.

I use the

```
  <MenuItem  value='09090' primaryText='hahah'/>
  <MenuItem  value='09090' primaryText='hahah'/>
  <MenuItem  value='09090' primaryText='hahah'/>
```

replace the code

```
 {member.hobbies.map( (item,keyIndex) =>
                     <MenuItem  key={keyIndex} value={keyIndex} primaryText='hahah'/>
```

The browser renders well.

I want to realize dynamic options of the select.

Anyway, can realize my goal is OK.
If you don't understand this problem after you have been read my description. I will edit this problem again.

Comment: where is that error points to?
which part of the code?

Comment: `member.hobbies.map `  Cannot read property 'map' of undefined        　　  I don't know how to pass data from `form.props` to `FieldArray`.

Answer (score 2):

When the app load the member.hobbies problably is not defined yet. Try to declare a variable to set this array as null if is not defined:

```
const hobbies = member.hobbies || []
```

and then:

```
{hobbies.map( (item,keyIndex) =>
                 <MenuItem  key={keyIndex} value={keyIndex} primaryText='hahah'/>
```

Comment: The hobbies is an asynchronous data, right? Try this solution, i think its solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You see, the console shows you that `hobbies` is undefined. Start from debugging the `fields`. What will you see after `console.log(fields);` in `renderMembers`?

Answer (score 0):

hopefully below snippet will help you,

```
{this.props.data.map((e, keyIndex) => {
return (<MenuItem key={keyIndex} value={e.warehouseId}>{e.name}</MenuItem>);
```

})
}